# Show that the group operation is well defined

Tags: group-theory

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$ and let $G/N=\{gH : g\in G\}.$

I'm trying to show that the group operation $$(xN)(yN)=(xy)N$$ is well defined.

Let $xN=x'N$ and let $yN=y'N$.

Next I'm told that the above implies that $x'=xn$ and $y'=yn'$ for some $n,n'\in N.$ I think I'm just missing something really obvious here but I don't understand why we have that implication. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prove that

$$\begin{cases}&(1)&xN=x'N\\{}\\&(2)&yN=y'N\end{cases}\implies (xN)(yN)=(x'N)(y'N)$$

and the last implies that we must show

$$xyN=x'y'N\iff (xy)^{-1}x'y'\in N\iff \color{red}{(*)}\;\;y^{-1}x^{-1}x'y'\in N\;$$

But we know that $\;x^{-1}x'=n\in N\;$ because of (1) above , so

$$\color{red}{(*)} = y^{-1}ny'=\overbrace{\left(y^{-1}ny\right)}^{\in N\lhd G}\,\overbrace{y^{-1}y'}^{\in N\,\text{because}\,(2)}\in N$$

and you've finished.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly $x' \in x'N$ as the identity element is in $N$. But $x'N=xN$, so $x' \in xN$ as well. Hence there exists $n \in N$ such that $x'=xn$. Similarly with $y'=yn'$.